# Help with sed script to remove Wikipedia citation numbers

Tags: sed, text-processing

I am just beginning to learn sed and awk. I have to submit an homework assignment tomorrow, which is a copy-paste from Wikipedia. Just the opportunity to practice some sed scripting!

So I have the document in html format. Now I need to replace `[<number>]` with nothing. How would I do this?

This is what I tried, but I think it does not even match the pattern I want:

```
cat content.xml | sed 's/\[\d+\]/ /g' > content2.xml
```

As a next stage, I will be implementing the replacement of these patterns, which are hyperlinks, but even the above mentioned simple pattern is not being matched:

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immune_system">immune system</a>
```

and then remove the citations:

```
<a name="cite_ref-Gleeson2007_27-0"/><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_exercise#cite_note-Gleeson2007-27">[27]</a>
```

Comment: "So I have the document in .odt format. I extract the content.xml file from it using Archive Manager." ... What? Why? O.o

Comment: @muru can I run sed scripts inside .odt files? Anyways, I've exported it to html file for simplicity. I've updated the question.

Comment: Neither `\d` nor the `+` modifier are recognized in BRE (Basic Regular Expression) syntax AFAIK: try `[0-9]\+` or (POSIX) `[0-9]\{1,\}` or switch to ERE (Extended Regular Expression) using the `-E` or `-r` switch. **However** you should generally try to avoid parsing HTML/XML using regular expressions: *"that way, madness lies"*.

Comment: daltonfury42 well, if you look at the HTML, the references are actually: `<span>[</span>N<span>]</span>`. Also, I second @steeldriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went the Wrong direction, you should learn XML/XSLT instead :)  (XML Style Sheet). Either for use with ODT or XHTML. For ODT, a macro may be be better, but I don't know it.

Make a look on this accepted answer: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/724406)

The solution in [this answer for How to replace all images in Libreoffice with their description](https://askubuntu.com/a/475041/26246) should work for you too with little modification.

Comment: Well, thanks for the suggestion. Actually I wanted to remove citation numbers from a lot of text. The work was due the next day. So I wrote a sed script and it did the job!